# WebSockets With Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

I am building a stock-based trading application and I am using Yahoo finance to get the prices for stocks.

I would like the prices to be updated every 5 seconds without having to refresh the page. How could I implement WebSockets to solve this?

```java
@GetMapping("/banking/stocks")
public String stocks(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("stock", new StockDto());
    try {
        List<Stock> stocks = stockService.getDefaultStocks(getCurrentUser());
        model.addAttribute("stocks", stocks);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "stocks.html";
}
```

This is the html page:

```java
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="stock : ${stocks}">
        <td th:text="'$'+${stock.getSymbol()}"></td>                                                    
        <td th:text="${stock.getName()}"></td>
        <td th:text="${stock.getQuote().getPrice()}"></td>
        <td
            th:class="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() > 0 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'}"
            th:text="${stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent() + '%'} "></td>
        <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() != null}"
            th:text="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() + '%'}">0.00%</td>
        <td th:if="${stock.getDividend().getAnnualYield() == null}">0.00%</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf? Just adding code for websocket connection in the script tag should do the trick. Check this: https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring

Comment: I've seen that article, but it's for STOMP messaging. I'm trying to a list of objects to my thymeleaf file every 30s using sockets. Do you know how to do this?